# Basic: Only one frame is played after rendering, and how do I make my plane/sheet thicker

Tags: rendering, animation

So I am trying to render my video, but after some time of rendering, the movie file only has 1 frame displayed.

I have checked my Frame Range, and have tried to change this a few times.  I can see the camera icon in my 'scene' info box.

It's going to be something obvious, but what am I doing wrong?

I am also in 'Object Mode' / 'Cycles render', and 'Solid view'.  I have tried going to Render -> Render Animation.

Attached is my file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr24ss1s460jsk4/FlagWorking.blend?dl=0

Another query - how can I make my plane / flag appear to be slightly thicker?

Lastly, when I play the animation within blender, it is pixelated, is there a way of having a clearer view?

Sorry for all the basic noob questions!  The main one is the first!

---

EDIT: I definitely have some animation when I play the it in Blender.

I have also tried exporting it as images but each image is just of the first frame.

I have tried starting from frame 0, or frame 1, or from frame 2 but still no luck.

[image]

---

EDIT: After Rob's suggestion of baking this happens....what do you think?
[image]

Comment: When I play the animation in that file there is no animation so frame 30 appears the same as frame 250. On the Physics tab click the bake button to calculate the animation. You can Add a Solidify Modifier to the flag to adjust its thickness. Currently the Flag is set Flat shaded, click the Smooth button on the Left hand panel to make it smooth.

Comment: Hi @rob Thanks for the tip.  How can you not see animation, but I can?  Please excuse my ignorance as I am still getting my head around Blender as you can tell.  Above is the animation I have playing in blender.   When I do hit the render button the, it does not go through all the frames like I have see on some YT videos.

Comment: Me again @rob, after baking something happened! But it's distorted :-/

Comment: Your modifier stack is the wrong a way around. Move the SubSurf Modifier down below the Physics Modifier and then turn your Wind down from 5000 to 50 and re-bake. The animation now renders correctly.

Comment: Thanks @rob, I can see how that will work.  It's now gone rigid like cardboard but that might be because of the way it was drawn.  I suppose I am going to have to start again from scratch :'(

Comment: It looked correct in the output video. Feel free to open another question if you get stuck on a different aspect.

Comment: Hi @rob thanks for your help today.  Still I am getting the distorted output in the render after switching the cloth and subsurface modifiers.  I seem to be getting conflicting information, as I have been told to do the other way around.  Do you know a simpler way of me getting a simple flag to flap in the wind?   An original questions for reference.

Comment: You can apply the Modifier so the Flag mesh gets the all the extra geometry permanently. The problem occurs when Blender has to non-destructively apply the SubSurf modifier dynamically while the cloth simulation is being calculated.

Comment: Thanks @rob - managed to get what I needed.  Really appreciate your help!